# Pass variable to different php file

Tags: php, mysql, variables, drupal-7

I am currently using Drupal 7.

I have pages that include php files that run a mysql query in them.

On the individual pages I have set variables unique to the pages so the mysql query will run based on what page is(variable assigned that page).

So far I have been unsuccessful to get the mysql to recognize the variables in the Drupal pages.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code Im currently using.

```
<?php
$fundnamedir ='8';
$ID_CARTERA='8'

require_once 'Queries/TableScript_Title.php';
require_once 'uploaded_files/individual_funds.php';
?>
```

Inside individual_funds.php it starts a process of creating charts which calls another chart.php file where the mysql is for displaying the data in a chart.

Comment: Show us some code so we can help you. You question is very vague.

Comment: search for `php global variables`

Comment: @crowjonah Yup search for that and forget all about it immediately.

Comment: Are you trying to use Drupal's globals? You have to be more specific as to what you're trying to do.

Comment: I would start with a so-called 'sanity-check'. Directly before `individual_funds.php` calls `chart.php`, echo the variable. Is it there? If it's not, trace the function calls back until you can determine exactly where it went missing.

Answer (score 1):

Included files inherit the scope from which they were called.

file1.php

```
<?php
    $var = "I'm a var.";
    include('file2.php');
?>
```

file2.php

```
<?php
    echo $var;
?>
```

Note that if you are placing the `include` inside a function, you will need to delare the variable as global in order for it to be visible. I suspect this might be why your page-specific variables aren't being received by your mysql scripts.

Modified file1.php

```
<?php
    $var = "I'm a var.";
    function func() {
        global $var;
        include('file2.php');
    }

    func();
?>
```

Comment: Other way around. If you include file1 in file 2 you can echo `$var`. Your way will give an undefined variable error.

Comment: Yes, if you `include` a script which sets a variable, it will remain set when execution returns to the calling script. But that doesn't solve the OP's problem. However, it works the other way around too. The code snippet I posted works exactly as written.

Comment: I see what you mean. Make an edit so I can take away the downvote. Your answer is a little misleading though. If you run file2.php you'll get an undefined variable error.

Comment: @JohnHarbert Format your comments so the it's easier to read or edit your original answer.

Comment: Without knowing the content of `indiviual_funds.php`, it's hard to say what the issue is. The small segment you've posted should work as written.

Comment: I added additional detail to my original post.